# Getting variable values from an external PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to get the results from a PHP file after the form has been posted:

*index.php (in http://domain2.com/)*

```
    <form  id='loginForm' action='http://domain1.com/mail.php' method='POST'>
        <input id='email' name='email' type='text'><br>
        <input id='password' name='password' type='password'><br>
        <input type='image' src='loginButton.png' alt ='Submit Form'/>
    </form>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            var error = "<?php echo json_encode($error); ?>";
            document.getElementById('email').value = error;
        });
    </script>
```

*mail.php (in http://domain1.com/)*

```
    <?php
    header('Location: http://domain2.com/');  //executes index.php
    $email = $_POST['email'];  //received correctly
    $password = $_POST['password'];  //received correctly
    ...
    ...
    ...
    $error = 'invalid id or password';
    ?>
```

However, the *$error* variable keeps returning null. The two scripts are in separate folders on the same server. How could I achieve this?

Thanks in advance,

Sofia

Comment: set your $error variable before your header

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I just tried moving the *header('Location...)* down; but it still returns null.

Comment: `header('Location: http://domain2.com/');  //executes index.php` Your comment is false, it doesn`t execute the script it redirects the user to that script. Any variable you set in your first php script will not follow. You need to send the error message to your second page...

Comment: Is mail.php included in index.php?

Comment: No; *mail.php* is not included in *index.php*. How would I do that?

Comment: And how would I *send the error message to the second page*, Bun?

Comment: OK, I think I see what's going on here. Sorry I misread your question. YOu need to use the .ajax() method in Jquery to post this form to mail.php.  Then you can return your error message.  Read this: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp to get started.

Comment: I'm afraid that Ajax is a little too advanced for my needs. I tried using sessions, but still, the *$_SESSION['error']* variable that I set in *mail.php* is returning null in *index.php*. I added the *session_start()* for both the scripts. Could this method be viable? And if yes, is my implementation wrong?

Comment: _“Could this method be viable?”_ – that depends on what your are actually trying to achieve with this – which you failed to describe properly so far. _“And if yes, is my implementation wrong?”_ – how are we supposed to know that, without seeing it? You should really go read [ask] first.

Comment: @iSofia From what I can tell from your code, you want to load the $error variable into your HTML without a page refresh.  If that's the case, you'll need to use .ajax().  The link I posted above is easy to follow, and you can find a plethora of tutorials online. The time you invest learning how to use it will be well worth it and will come in handy in every other project you do from now on.

Comment: CBroe: I've since found out that the *session* route does not work between different domains, unless some means of alternate storage were to be used *(eg. database)*. And Chris *(ChrisWillard)*; yes, all I want is to get the error message from *mail.php* to display it in *index.php*, but it does not really matter if the page refreshes or not. I truly appreciate your help; I've posted my failed Ajax attempt below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matter resolved! Apparently this issue revolves around cross-domain communications, which is a whole other beast. Amidst all the replies, *funny no one caught that*.

Anyway, I've managed to circumvent it by utilising a cURL broker, with the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option.

My thanks to ChrisWillard; appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for using the answer section, but since the approach has changed, this is what I've come up with, Ajax-wise:

*index.php (in http://domain2.com/)*

```
<form  id='loginForm' action='http://domain1.com/mail.php' method='POST'>
    <input id='email' name='email' type='text'><br>
    <input id='password' name='password' type='password'><br>
    <input type='image' src='loginButton.png' alt ='Submit Form'/>
</form>

<script type='text/javascript'>
        var frm = $('#loginForm');
        frm.submit(function (ev)
        {
            $.ajax(
            {
                    type: frm.attr('method'),
                    url: frm.attr('action'),
                    data: frm.serialize(),
                    success: function (data)
                    {
                        alert('submitted!');
                    }
            });
            ev.preventDefault();
        });                     
</script>
```

*mail.php (in http://domain1.com/)*

```
<?php
        //header('Location: http://domain2.com/');
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        ...
        ...
        echo 'invalid id or password';
?>
```

Firstly, it's not executing the *alert('submitted!')*, and secondly, where would the response come in? Also, does it need some special Ajax plugin, or would the standard jQuery 1.10.1 work?

Since I need Ajax only in the case of errors, is there a way for the *mail.php* to re-direct to another page if there are no errors?

Thanks again for all the help and suggestions.

Sofia